# How can I allocate and initialize a custom UITableViewCell NOT in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I won't go into the WHY on this one, I'll just explain what I need.

I have a property in my implementatioon file like so...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyCustomCell *customCell;
```

I need to initialize this on viewDidLoad. I return it as a row in cellForRowAtIndexPath always for the same indexPath, by returning "self.customCell".

However it doesn't work, I don't appear to be allocating and initializing the custom cell correctly in viewDidLoad. **How can I do this**? If you know the answer, save yourself time and don't read any further.

---

Ok, I'll put the *why* here in case people are curious.

I had a table view which was 2 sections. The first section would always show 1 row (Call it A). The second section always shows 3 rows (Call them X, Y, Z).

If you tap on row A (which is S0R0[Section 0 Row]), a new cell would appear in S0R1. A cell with a UIPickerView. The user could pick data from the UIPickerView and this would update the chosen value in cell A.

Cell X, Y & Z all worked the same way. Each could be tapped, and they would open up another cell underneath with their own respective UIPickerView.

The way I WAS doing this, was all these cell's were created in the Storyboard in the TableView, and then dragged out of the View. IBOutlets were created for all. Then in cellForRAIP, I would just returned self.myCustomCellA, or self.myCustomCellY.

Now, this worked great, but I need something more custom than this. I need to use a custom cell, and not just a UITableViewCell. So instead of using IBOutlets for all the cells (8 cells, 4 (A,X,Y,Z) and their 4 hidden/toggle-able UIPickerView Cell's), I created @properties for them in my implementation file. But it's not working like it did before with the standard UITableViewCell.

I'm not sure I'm initializing them correctly? How can I properly initialize them in/off viewDidLoad so I can use them?

---

.m

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) MyCustomCell *myCustomCellA;
...
```

viewDidLoad

```
...
self.myCustomCellA = [[MyCustomCell alloc] init];
...
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
...
return self.myCustomCellA;
...
```

Comment: Update your question with how you create the cell in `viewDidLoad` and how you use it in `cellForRow...`.

Answer (score 0):

If only I understood your question correctly, you have 3 options:

1. I would try really hard to implement table view data source with regular dynamic cells lifecycle in code and not statically – this approach usually pays off when you inevitably want to modify your business logic.
2. If you are certain [static table view](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/05/07/static-table-views-with-storyboards.html) is enough, you can mix this method with overriding data source / delegate methods in your subclass of table view controller to add minor customisation (e.g. hiding certain cell when needed)
3. Alternatively, you can create cells using designated initialiser `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` to instantiate them outside of table view life cycle and implement completely custom logic. There is nothing particular that you should do in `viewDidLoad`, that you wouldn't do elsewhere.

If you have a particular problem with your code, please post a snippet so community can help you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to declare all your cells in storyboard (with date picker at right position) as static table and then override tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Define BOOL for determine picker visibility and its position in table

```
#define DATE_PICKER_INDEXPATH [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]

@interface YourViewController ()
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isPickerVisible;
@end
```

Then setup initial value

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.isPickerVisible = YES;
}
```

Override tableView delegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([indexPath isEqual:DATE_PICKER_INDEXPATH] && !self.isPickerVisible) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

And finally create method for toggling picker

```
- (void)togglePicker:(id)sender {
    self.isPickerVisible = !self.isPickerVisible;
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

which you can call in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

According to your problem, you can create pairs (NSDictionary) of index path and bool if its visible and show/hide them according to that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was looking for:

```
MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[[[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyNibName" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] firstObject];
```